JFrameChart Sliding Bandwidth Window
I am trying to get a green sliding window overlay correctly placed on a JFrameChart, and have gotten close, however, there is still overlaps on the top and bottom of the green sliding window. I have scoured through the documentation and codebase for JFrameChart to no avail or good sense of direction to figuring out the problem.
Here is the code I have so far, and have attached a screenshot of the graph window.
 private void createSlidingBandwidthFilterWindow() {
        double width = chartPanel.getWidth();
        double height = chartPanel.getHeight();
        
        JPanel jPanelSlidingBandwidthFilterWindow = new JPanel()
        {
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                g.setColor(getBackground());
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        jPanelSlidingBandwidthFilterWindow.setOpaque(false);
        jPanelSlidingBandwidthFilterWindow.setBackground( new Color(0, 255, 0, 20 ));
        
        jPanelSlidingBandwidthFilterWindow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 367));
        chartPanel.add(jPanelSlidingBandwidthFilterWindow);    
}

public void setGraphValues(double[] freqs, double[] magnitudes) {          
        lineChart = ChartFactory.createAreaChart("Fourier Transform",
            "Frequency (Hz)", "Magnitude",
            createFFTDataset(freqs, magnitudes),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true,true,false);
        
        chartPanel = new ChartPanel(lineChart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800 , 367));
        jInternalFrameGraph.setContentPane(chartPanel);
        BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI)jInternalFrameGraph.getUI();
        Container north = (Container)ui.getNorthPane();
        north.remove(0);
        north.validate();
        north.repaint();
        
        chartPanel.setVisible(true);  
        Range range = chartPanel.getChart().getCategoryPlot().getRenderer().findRangeBounds(createFFTDataset(freqs, magnitudes));
        System.out.println("Lower Bound: " + range.getLowerBound());
        System.out.println("Upper Bound: " + range.getUpperBound());
        createSlidingBandwidthFilterWindow();
}     


